# Implementing push feed in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement push feed in nodejs provided by sportradar (https://developer.sportradar.com/docs/read/american_football/NFL_v6#push-feeds)

It uses HTTP publish/subscribe model

They already provide it for java and python but tried to look into node js but not found something

I have looked into https://github.com/scripting/feedRead but that is used to read xml but here sportradar push feed is providing json

It returns json response in the following format: https://developer.sportradar.com/files/NFL_v6_Push_Clock_Example.json

Comment: What does a push feed response look like? What type of streaming does it use?

Comment: @Matt It uses HTTP publish/subscribe model and and i have added example json in the quesiton

Comment: pub/sub is the model, the docco says it uses http chunked responses. [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) can stream requests and [ndjson](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson.js) can parse a newline delimited stream

Comment: if a `curl` works, axios should be able to do it

Comment: oh.. their `curl` commands should read `curl -LX GET ...`

Comment: So do i have to call the api multiple times ?

Comment: No, a single request. The response doesn't end. They keep appending data to the same response (i.e chunks). They add in a "ping" every 5 seconds so it actively avoids being timed out somewhere.

Comment: Ok will try to implement it using axios

Comment: Nihal, do you have any examples of what you ended up implementing? Thanks!